# Getting Value of a Double Variable as Infinity

Tags: kotlin, double

**Code:**

```
var num = Math.pow(2.0, 5.0)
num = Math.pow(5.0, num)
num = Math.pow(2.0, num)
print(num)
```

**Output:**

```
Infinity
```

When I run the above code I am getting the value as Infinity. I can't understand what's happening. Is it crossing the limit of the **double** variable? Also, `Math.pow()` method will always return a **double**.

I have to run the above code and need the value of **num** variable. How can I solve it?

Actually, I have to compare two numbers after the calculation of exponential programmatically to determine which one is higher?

Like: (2^(5^(2^5))) or (5^(2^(5^2))). So, which one is higher?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That number has a sextillion digits. Of course it's higher than the upper range of double.

Comment: @Michael But the Math.pow() method will always return a double variable. Also, that method takes double variable as parameters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not even BigInteger will allow you to do `2^23283064365386962890625`. Basically you should just *very carefully* rethink whether this is even necessary. It's almost certainly not.

Comment: The real question is : Why you have to deal with numbers of this size ? :o

Comment: I am posting the actual question.

Comment: Why do you have to do "the calculation of exponential" at all? You can determine which number is higher without calculating the actual values. Are the actual values really part of the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinity is a legal value for `double` and what you'll get whenever your result sufficiently exceeds the maximum number representable as a `double` (~1.8*10^308). This isn't the only "special" value: there are also negative infinity, negative zero, NaN, subnormal numbers.

There are many sources on how floating point numbers work, you can start here: http://floating-point-gui.de/

> I have to run the above code and need the value of num variable. How can I solve it?

When you run this code, the value of `num` *is* infinity. There's nothing to solve there.

> Actually, I have to compare two numbers after the calculation of exponential programmatically to determine which one is higher?
>
> Like: (2^(5^(2^5))) or (5^(2^(5^2))). So, which one is higher?

You can't use `double` for that if the numbers are too large, period. Try calculating and comparing their logarithms or logarithms of logarithms.

Comment: You doesn't purpose an answer to Avijit's question. He doesn't have to know why double is not suitable for his use case. He search a solution to store his number who doesn't fit in a double (and a way to compute pow on it).

Comment: Sorry for asking that type of question. I am new in Kotlin. I didnot get anything that shows that double can have a infinity

Comment: Thanks to @Alexey. I am also thinking about logarithm. I have solved the problem using logarithm.